# Convert text file to hex - New Line problem

Tags: python, hex

I'm trying to convert a text file to hexadecimal and then back to a text again. It works well as long as I do not use new line.

The first function take te filename and returns a list with integers that represents each letter.

```
    block = []
    file = open(filename, 'rb')
    content = file.read()
    
    hexstring = binascii.hexlify(content)

    for i in range(0,len(hexstring),2):
        block.append(int(hexstring[i:i+2], base=16))

    return block
```

This is how I convert back to plaintext.

```
for i in range(len(stringList)):
    tmp = stringList[i]
    for j in range(len(tmp)):
        hexString = str(hex(tmp[j]))
        hexString = hexString.replace('0x', '') 
        pt = bytearray.fromhex(hexString).decode()
        plainText.append(pt)
```

The code is awful but works as long as I do not have a new line. Then I get the following error.

```
pt = bytearray.fromhex(hexString).decode()
ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try using codecs modules
>
> ```
> import codecs
>
> def encode():
>     with open(file='sample.txt') as file:
>         text = file.read()
>     return codecs.encode(bytes(text, encoding='utf-8'), "hex")
>
> def decode(encodedString):
>     return codecs.decode(encodedString, 'hex')
>
>
> a = encode()
> b = decode(a)
>
> print(a)
> print(b)
> ```

Comment: If you use a text file with new line, they are not left at decode. Is there a solution if you want to decode the text file in exactly as it looks originally?